# Selecting features "above" or "below" a line using R

Tags: r, sf

Given a line and a set of points, I can't figure out how to use `sf` to identify which side of the line each point falls.

A small reproducible example follows, adapted from a [different question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243994/how-to-calculate-distance-from-point-to-linestring-in-r-using-sf-library-and-g)

```
# Load Libraries ----------------------------------------------------------

library('sf')

# Test data ---------------------------------------------------------------

points.df <- data.frame(
    'x' = c(-53.50000, -54.15489, -54.48560, -52.00000, -52.57810, -49.22097, -48.00000),
    'y' = c(-38.54859, -41.00000, -38.80000, -38.49485, -38.00000, -40.50000, -37.74859)
)


line.df <- data.frame(
    'x' = c(-54.53557, -52.00000, -50.00000, -48.00000, -46.40190),
    'y' = c(-39.00000, -38.60742, -38.08149, -38.82503, -37.00000)
)

# Create 'sf' objects -----------------------------------------------------

points.sf <- st_as_sf(points.df, coords = c("x", "y"))

st_crs(points.sf) <- st_crs(4326) # assign crs

line.sf <- st_sf(id = 'L1', st_sfc(st_linestring(as.matrix(line.df), dim = "XY")))
st_crs(line.sf) <- st_crs(4326) # assign crs


# Plots -------------------------------------------------------------------

xmin <- min(st_bbox(points.sf)[1], st_bbox(line.sf)[1])
ymin <- min(st_bbox(points.sf)[2], st_bbox(line.sf)[2])
xmax <- max(st_bbox(points.sf)[3], st_bbox(line.sf)[3])
ymax <- max(st_bbox(points.sf)[4], st_bbox(line.sf)[4])

plot(points.sf, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude",
     xlim = c(xmin,xmax), ylim = c(ymin,ymax), graticule = st_crs(4326), axes = TRUE)

plot(line.sf, col = "#C72259", add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(points.sf), as.character(1:7), pos = 3)
```

[image: plot output]

In this example, it's easy to verify that points 2 and 6 fall south of the line, and the rest north. How can I automate the labeling?

Non `sf` based answers are welcome too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer provided is related to this question [How to subset a SpatialPoints object to get the points located on each side of a SpatialLines object using R?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP3bO.png) but using `sf` library instead of `sp`.

Check the commented code below.

```
# Load Libraries ----------------------------------------------------------

library('sf')

# Test data ---------------------------------------------------------------

points.df <- data.frame(
  'x' = c(-53.50000, -54.15489, -54.48560, -52.00000, -52.57810, -49.22097, -48.00000),
  'y' = c(-38.54859, -41.00000, -38.80000, -38.49485, -38.00000, -40.50000, -37.74859),
  'id' = as.character(c(1:7))
)


line.df <- data.frame(
  'x' = c(-54.53557, -52.00000, -50.00000, -48.00000, -46.40190),
  'y' = c(-39.00000, -38.60742, -38.08149, -38.82503, -37.00000)
)

# Create 'sf' objects -----------------------------------------------------

points.sf <- st_as_sf(points.df, coords = c("x", "y"))

st_crs(points.sf) <- st_crs(4326) # assign crs

line.sf <- st_sf(id = 'L1', st_sfc(st_linestring(as.matrix(line.df), dim = "XY")))
st_crs(line.sf) <- st_crs(4326) # assign crs    

# Plots -------------------------------------------------------------------

xmin <- min(st_bbox(points.sf)[1], st_bbox(line.sf)[1])
ymin <- min(st_bbox(points.sf)[2], st_bbox(line.sf)[2])
xmax <- max(st_bbox(points.sf)[3], st_bbox(line.sf)[3])
ymax <- max(st_bbox(points.sf)[4], st_bbox(line.sf)[4])

plot(points.sf, pch = 19, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude",
     xlim = c(xmin,xmax), ylim = c(ymin,ymax), graticule = st_crs(4326), axes = TRUE)

plot(line.sf, col = "#272822", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(points.sf), as.character(points.sf$id), pos = 3)
```

[image: map1]

```
# Create Polygons from line -----------------------------------------------

# Add x and y offsets (in degrees units)
offsetX <- 0
offsetY <- 3

polySideUp <- rbind(c(st_bbox(line.sf)['xmax'] + offsetX, 
                       st_bbox(line.sf)['ymax'] + offsetY),
                     c(st_bbox(line.sf)['xmin'] - offsetX, 
                       st_bbox(line.sf)['ymax'] + offsetY),
                     as.data.frame(st_coordinates(line.sf))[,c(1,2)],
                     c(st_bbox(line.sf)['xmax'] + offsetX, 
                       st_bbox(line.sf)['ymax'] + offsetY))

polySideDown <- rbind(c(st_bbox(line.sf)['xmax'] + offsetX, 
                       st_bbox(line.sf)['ymin'] - offsetY),
                     c(st_bbox(line.sf)['xmin'] - offsetX, 
                       st_bbox(line.sf)['ymin'] - offsetY),
                     as.data.frame(st_coordinates(line.sf))[,c(1,2)],
                     c(st_bbox(line.sf)['xmax'] + offsetX, 
                       st_bbox(line.sf)['ymin'] - offsetY))

# Create sf objects
polySideUp <- st_sf("id" = 'sideUp', st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(polySideUp))), crs = 4326))
polySideDown <- st_sf("id" = 'sideDown', st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(polySideDown))), crs = 4326))

# Plot
plot(polySideUp, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", col = "#C72259", 
     xlim = c(xmin - offsetX, xmax + offsetX), ylim = c(ymin - offsetY, ymax + offsetY), graticule = st_crs(4326), axes = TRUE)
plot(polySideDown, col = "#53A8BD", add = TRUE)
plot(points.sf$geometry, pch = 19, add = TRUE)
plot(line.sf, col = "#272822", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(points.sf), as.character(points.sf$id), pos = 3)
```

[image: map2]

```
# Select points in side up
pointsInSideUp <- st_intersection(points.sf, polySideUp)

print(pointsInSideUp)
```

[image: print1]

```
# Select points in side down
pointsInSideDown <- st_intersection(points.sf, polySideDown)

print(pointsInSideDown)
```

[image: print2]

```
# Plot intersection
plot(polySideUp, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", col = "#C72259", 
     xlim = c(xmin - offsetX, xmax + offsetX), ylim = c(ymin - offsetY, ymax + offsetY), graticule = st_crs(4326), axes = TRUE)
plot(polySideDown, col = "#53A8BD", add = TRUE)
plot(pointsInSideUp, pch = 19, col = "#53A8BD", add = TRUE)
plot(pointsInSideDown, pch = 19, col = "#C72259", add = TRUE)
plot(line.sf, lwd = 2, col = "#272822", add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(points.sf), as.character(points.sf$id), pos = 3)
```

[image: map3]

Comment: Transforming to a different CRS might not be the right thing to do - its possible the questioner would rather have "north" and "south" refer to latitude. I don't know why you chose that particular one because its a bit rotated compared to lat-long at that point. I'd stick with lat-long or a mercator. I'll delete my answer because this is a nice implementation of my outline.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman! Do you mean transforming to crs 32721? You are right that is not necessary. It's UTM zone 21 South; I think that the points fall in that zone but I'm not sure. I will modify my answer using crs 4326. Thanks!

Comment: The OP asked above/below in the context of 32721, if that's not what was intended then the Q should be updated, not this answer to the current Q. (The Q includes above/below and north/south so it's strictly ambiguous atm).

Comment: CRS 32721 in my original Q got there simply because it was used in the code snippet that I re-purposed... my bad! I've updated my question to get rid of the potentially confusing transformation from 4326 to 3721.

Answer (score 7):

Outline algorithm, which also gives a stronger definition of "north or south" of the line:

Turn the line into a polygon by adding two extra line segments from the end points down to Y=-Infinity, or at least further south than the southernmost point. Then do a point-in-polygon test. Points in the polygon are south of the line.

Repeat to create a polygon with infinity (or large) positive extra segments. That gives you points north of the line.

Points in neither polygon are undefined as to their north-south of the line nature - they are east or west of the line.